# SSIS reading Dynamic CSV

Tags: csv, memory-management, ssis, 32bit-64bit

I have a file where the total columns could change, ie sometimes a column may be missed.
As I understand the standard import process will not handle that, so I am to use a script task.  I have created the code and it works fine, to a point.
1) releasing to the destination server causes the Jet driver to fail (as it's 32 bit)
2) The read runs out of memory

I need ideas/solution that will support a 64 bit destination server, and also handle memory

The actual file being ingested isn't that large, so the memory exception may just be a 32 bit issue.

Comment: The way I deal with variable column text files is that I import the entire file into a _one_ field staging table, then inspect and shred it out using string functions.

Comment: Did you now all possible columns name? all file has the same delimiter and text qualifier?

Comment: why use the jet driver? Its a csv right? you can just use a flat file source and specify the delimiters and run it in a 64bit environment. Like Nick said i do the same thing sort of but i use a script with a nested loop by dumping lines of text file into an array based on row delimiter. then parse each line by throwing it in another array based on col delimiters.